# Tab character inside select option

Tags: html-select

I have an `<Option>` inside a `<select>` on my HTML-Form.

For better visibility, I want to use a TAB inside my Option.

Now the selection is in the Dropdown displayed as:

1. Mister Test - Technician
2. Misses VeryLongTest - Accounting
3. Mister X - Housekeeping

I instead want it displayed like:

1/........Mister Test........................- Technician

2/........Misses VeryLongTest.......- Accounting

545/....Mister X............................- Housekeeping

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: ... by adding periods to your `<option>` text?

Comment: You would need to use javascript or PHP in order to do it dynamically, otherwise you would have to just do it by adding spaces.

Comment: Spaces or periods are likely to result in misalignment as font character widths vary. It's not a good solution.

Comment: @isherwood Not really. Though different styles for different parts of the option would solve the problem, it is not the same problem

Comment: @isherwood and if font widths are an issue... [monospaced fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) could help with that...  :)

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot do that. Content inside `<option>` tag is treated as plain text. It doesn't recognize any tabs nor markups. You need to use spaces unfortunately.

As it was said in question's comments it is possible to write a script for that. Unfortunately, if you cannot do it with spaces you will not be able to make a proper script. You would need a const width font like `Courier new`. Then you can easily write the script for that:

```
function alignedOptionText(spaceAvailble, beforeTab, afterTab) {
    spaces = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < beforeTab.length; ++i)
        spaces += " ";
    return beforeTab + spaces + afterTab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom `select` via JS. In such custom `select`, each option could contain any markup that could be styled as a table as you wish.